# How can I return value after get-request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, needle.js

How can I get this value when I get a response from the server?

The terminal is not outputing any information when I run it.

```js
console.log(a);
function findMaxID() {
    var a = needle.get(URL, function(err, res){
        if (err) throw err;
        return 222; 
    });
    return a;
}
```

Comment: @BelminBedak Can you show me a simple of code? I'm used promisses many times, but here, in this example my promises don't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises might be of help.

Answer (score 5):

Basicly, you can't really `return` this value in the way functions return values. what you CAN do is give your `findMaxID()` function a **callback** parameter to be called when the data is fetched :

```
function findMaxID(callback) {
    needle.get(URL, function(err, res){
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(res); 
    });
}
```

then call it like this :

```
findMaxID(function(id) {
    console.log('Max ID is : ', id);
}
```

You can also return a **promise** :

```
function findMaxID() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        needle.get(URL, function(err, res){
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(res);
        });
    });
}
```

And call it like this :

```
findMaxID().then(function(id) {
    console.log('Max ID is ', id);
})
```

### EDIT

Or like this if you're under an `async` function :

```
var id = await findMaxId();
console.log(id); // logs the ID
```